# I do not understand the behaviour of #define macro in C++

Tags: c++, macros, constants

I need to understand how this code works:

```c++
#define foo1( a ) (a * a)              // How does this work?
inline int foo2( int a ) { return (a * a); }
int goo1( int x ) { return foo1(foo2(x)); }
int goo2( int& x ) { return x = foo2(foo1(x)); }
int goo3( int& x, int y ) { return foo2(foo1(y + 1)); }
void goo4( int& x, int y ) { x = foo1(foo2(y + 1)); }

int main(){
int i = 2, j = 1, a = 2+3;

cout << "foo1 = " << foo1( 1+2 ) << "\n";  // How does this work?
cout << "foo2 = " << foo2( 2 + 1 ) << "\n";
cout << "goo1 = " << goo1( i ) << "\n";
cout << "goo2 = " << goo2( j ) << "\n";
cout << "goo3 = " << goo3( i, j ) << "\n";  // How does this work?
goo4( i, j );
cout << " i = " << i << " j = " << j << "\n";
}
```

But I do not seem to be able understand the behaviour of this function:

```
#define foo1( a ) (a * a)
```

and hence I don't understand the output of these two function calls:

```
foo1( 1+2 )
goo3( i, j )
```

This is the output of the program:

```
foo1 = 5
foo2 = 9
goo1 = 16
goo2 = 1
goo3 = 9
 i = 16 j = 1
```

I can't see why foo1 is not behaving like foo2. Would someone explain to me how this #define macro works?

NOTE: I must not change the code, I am only trying to understand the output.

Comment: this is why you do inline functions rather than #defines

Comment: try `#define foo1( a ) ((a) *( a)) ` if you must use defines

Comment: #define foo1(a) ((a) * (a)).  You haven't lived macros until you know C and learned not to use them.

Comment: I get the expected output when I call it with only one int, for example `foo(5)` will give me 25, which is simply 5 * 5. But why is the output of foo1(1+2) not 9 (which is 3*3)?

Comment: I have been given this code and I only need to understand the output, so I cannot change it. @pm100

Comment: the answer is below

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's really simple.

```
foo1( 1 + 2 )
```

will turn into:

```
( 1 + 2 * 1 + 2 )
```

which is actually:

```
1 + 2 + 2 = 5
```

This is how macros work.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are not functions.

Macros do TEXT replacement.  So when you have

```
#define foo1( a )   (a * a)
```

any instance of `foo1(` ... `)` with anything between then parenthesis will be expanded AS TEXT, not as an expression.  So when you have `foo1( 1 + 2 )` it turns into `( 1 + 2 * 1 + 2 )`

Comment: Well, thank you so much! It was way easier than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Macro is not a function.
The compiler will expand all macros and then compile it. To see the expanded code, you can use the following command using -E option in gcc:

```
gcc -E <source code> -o <preprocessed file name>
```

Or in Visual C++, under Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor, set "Generate Preprocessed File".

BTW, your macro is problematic.
You should use

```
#define foo1( a ) ((a) * (a))
```

instead of

```
 #define foo1( a ) (a * a)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have only been given this code to understand what it does, I know the macro is problematic, but it's meant to be like that for learning purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is, the foo1 defined by #define is **NOT a function**, while foo2 is.

In compilation process, the compiler will replace the foo1(parameter) keyword in your code with (parameter * parameter).

Meaning,

`cout << "foo1 = " << foo1( 1+2 ) << "\n";  // How does this work`?

will be replaced by the following code,

`cout << "foo1 = " << ( 1+2 * 1+2 ) << "\n";  // How does this work`?

(Because the parameter here is 1+2, instead of 3.)

The result is 1+2 * 1+2, which is 5.

Now let look at foo2, since it is **an inline function**, the compiler will not replace it. When your code is compiled into an executable file, and the executable file is executed, the **2 + 1** expression will be calculated first, and the result, 3, will then be passed to foo2().

In conclusion, the difference really lies in the compilation of your code. You may need more knowledge on what happens there.